# Cocos2d-iphone: Shooting laser from alien ship

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

How do I check if the ship sprite and alien sprite are on the same x-axis? I did the following.their x-position is not meeting at some point. Note: the enemy is moving from the right to left, the ship is moving from the left to right.

```
    if(enemy2.visible) {
    NSLog(@"enemy x %f", enemy2.position.x);
    NSLog(@"ship x %f", _ship.position.x);
if( enemy2.position.x < _ship.position.x)
{

        CCSprite *laser =  [_enemiesLasers objectAtIndex:_nextEnemyLaser];
        if (_nextEnemyLaser >= _enemiesLasers.count) _nextEnemyLaser = 0;
        _nextEnemyLaser++;
        [laser stopAllActions];
        laser.position=enemy2.position;
        // laser.rotation=45;
        laser.visible=YES;
        [laser runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:5 position:ccp(_ship.position.y, laser.position.x)], [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setInvisible:)] , nil]];
    }
   }
```

this is the NSLog output:

```
    2013-12-26 23:54:24.300 SpaceGame[3559:907] enemy x 540.000000
    2013-12-26 23:54:24.301 SpaceGame[3559:907] ship x 291.999969
    2013-12-26 23:54:27.301 SpaceGame[3559:907] enemy x 540.000000
    2013-12-26 23:54:27.302 SpaceGame[3559:907] ship x 109.999985
    2013-12-26 23:54:30.366 SpaceGame[3559:907] enemy x 540.000000
    2013-12-26 23:54:30.366 SpaceGame[3559:907] ship x 269.999969
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if they are at the exact same x position, like in the game Space Invaders, you **could** use something like this:

```
int enemyPosX = (int)enemy.position.x;
int shipPosX = (int)_ship.position.x;
if( enemy2.position.x < _ship.position.x)
{
  // Do Something
}
```

You will note that the floating point values have been cast to "ints".  This is because it is very hard to get exactly the same two floating point numbers once you start using them in operations.  The lowest order bits may be off, and then they are not equal.

You may also check if they are just "really close" to each other, where the "closeness" is defined by a tolerance value in your game:

```
if(fabs(enemy2.position.x - _ship.position.x) < NEAR_IN_X)
{
   // Do Something
}
```

Note that this is a check to see if they are "overlapping" in the x dimension.  Depending on how far they move each update, they may continue to overlap after the first time, so you may need to keep track of "state" of a collision-like-thing (e.g. { NOT_OVERLAPPING, BEGIN_OVERLAPPING, OVERLAPPING, END_OVERLAPPING }).  This is almost the same thing you would do with a physics engine for colliding objects.

Even if you take the first solution doing just "int" conversion, you may still have to handle multiple "overlap" states.

Was this helpful?

Comment: Yes, this was helpful. Thanks! What I did yesterday was putting the checking code, the collision code and firing lasers code in one method. I separated them and everything works fine now. :D

Comment: You should consider using a 2-d physics engine like box2d.  There are lots of tutorials and it has collision detection between shapes built into the foundation.